# How to change Ruby hash default value to arbitrary object after it has been created?

Tags: ruby, hash, associative-array

This is my code:

```
[164] pry(main)> h = Hash.new "A"
=> {}
[165] pry(main)> h["x"]
=> "A"
[166] pry(main)> h["x"] = "XXX"
=> "XXX"
[167] pry(main)> h["x"]
=> "XXX"
[168] pry(main)> h["y"].downcase!
=> "a"
[169] pry(main)> h["y"]
=> "a"
[170] pry(main)> h["z"]
=> "a"
[171] pry(main)>
```

As you can see, I can create a hash `h` with a default value `A`. After `h` has been created, I can change this default value to its `downcase!`, which is `a`. Here my question is, how can I change it to arbitrary value, like `"xyz"`. Apparently I can't use something like `h["not-exist"] = "xyz";`, as that will create the new key with the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Hash#default=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D) to set the default value.

```
h = Hash.new "A"
#=> {}
h.default = "xyz"
#=> "xyz"
h["non-exist"]
#=> "xyz"
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed this `default` method.

Comment: It's not the `default` method, it's the `default=` method.